# Hot Water Pressure low on 3 faucets

Tags: water-pressure

I have 3 faucets, 1 on the main floor, and 2 in a bathroom directly above it, that have very low water pressure only from the hot water side. The bathtub in the same upstairs bathroom has great hot water pressure.
Any idea what would be causing these 3 faucets to all have low hot water pressure?
I have checked the valves attaching the faucet to the water line and they are all turned on. 
They are the same brand of faucet, but it seems the likelihood that all of them would fail is low.

Comment: Perhaps there is another valve that you haven't found yet.

Comment: Are there are other faucets in the house that have normal hot water flow, kitchen, laundry room, other bathrooms, etc?  Has this always being the case, or how long have the three faucets being experiencing low flow?  Does the cold water flow with pressure?